# С - Why scanf() in if() statement works incorrect?

Tags: c

I am trying to make calculator in command line application, but when I use
`

```
int a, b, result;
printf("Enter problem:\n");

if(scanf("%i+%i", &a, &b))
{
    result = a + b;
    printf("%i\n", result);
}
else if(scanf("%i*%i", &a, &b))
{
    result = a * b;
    printf("%i\n", result);
}
```

If I write `5+5` , I have `10`, but when I `5*5` it shows `32771`. If I swap those statements, when I write `5*5` , I have 25, but when I write `5+5`, I have `32771` too. Thanks in advance for answer!

Comment: The validation is incomplete. Should be `f(scanf("%i+%i", &a, &b) == 2)` Why? `scanf()` returns the number of **successful** conversions that took place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(scanf("%i+%i", &a, &b))
```

that line makes no sense as `scanf` returns the number of **successfully** scanned items.

If you want to check if `scanf` succeeded

```
if(scanf("%i+%i", &a, &b) == 2)
```

The rest is invalid as `scanf` reads the data from the input stream and the second `scanf` will not have the full line to scan.

```
char line[100];
fgets(line, 100, stdin);  // check for errors
if(sscanf(line, "%i+%i", &a, &b) == 2)
{
    result = a + b;
    printf("%i\n", result);
}
else if(sscanf(line, "%i*%i", &a, &b) == 2)
{
    result = a * b;
    printf("%i\n", result);
}
else
{
    printf("Invalid Input\n");
}
```

Comment: You can leave spaces between `%i` and `+`. This way, ` 5  +    5` would be valid input too.

Comment: @Zakk the answer is not about it. Of course, it is not a good method of parsing expressions.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `scanf` works differently to what you think it does.

If you write "5*5" and use the above code, the first if statement is executed. `scanf` scans string, parses the first number and then it hits '*' which DOES NOT match the format string. `scanf` exits and returns 1 as this is the number of matched strings. The first branch is executed and you are using uninitialized variable `b` in the addition hence the nonsense result.

If you want to parse arithmetic operations you have to write the logic yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have pointed out, you're not using `scanf` correctly - if you type `5 * 5`, the first `scanf` successfully reads `5` into `a`, then bails because `*` isn't the expected `+` and `b` isn't updated.  However, because you had one successful conversion and assignment, `scanf` returns 1 so the first branch is taken.

While this is Not The Way To Do It™, a quick-and-dirty solution would be to scan for *three* inputs - the two operands and the operator, then branch based on the value of the operator:

```
int a, b, result;
char op;

if ( scanf( "%d %c %d", &a, &op, &b ) == 3 )
{
  switch( op )
  {
    case '+' : result = a + b; break;
    case '-' : result = a - b; break;
    case '*' : result = a * b; break;
    case '/' : result = a / b; break;
    default: fprintf( stderr, "Unrecognized operator %c - exiting\n", op ); return -1;
  }
}
else
{
  fprintf( "Badly formatted input...exiting\n" );
  return -1;
}
printf( "%d %c %d = %d", a, op, b, result );
```

Usually, though, parsing arithmetic expressions is a little more involved than that.